# Sharing to Facebook doesn't pick up Title, Description etc

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api

When I paste in the url of my page on Facebook, it doesn't pick the title etc.

I've got this in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<meta property="og:title" content="Baten 2012">
<meta property="og:type" content="website" >
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.nygeneration.se/båten/img/fb.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.nygeneration.se/båten/"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Jesus. 2000 ungdomar. EN STÖRT. STOR. BÅT.">
```

But it doesn't work. [Facebook's url debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) says that the url and title aren't declared, but as far as I know they are. What am I missing here? The page in question is [here.](http://www.nygeneration.se/b%C3%A5ten/)

Interesting fact by the way is that if I serve the page from the Public folder of my Dropbox it does work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem I've seen is that the sharer.php cache everything really hard so it could be a little bit hard coding as "try/trial and error". I create meta tags from code-behind/serverside and in the end of links for urls and images I add ?v=DATETIME so the result will be like; ../image.jpg?v=20120217120412,.. works like a charm!

the meta tags look good, I do not use the extra xmlns:xx i the html tag, works anyway

Comment: The Facebook debugger always resets the cache, so that's not really neccessary.

Comment: I had the same problem, and i spent several hours for solving problem - and problem was in cache.

Answer (score 1):

You should close all `meta` tags with />

the `<html>` also missing.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: Fixed this, but doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I think there is only one thing could be missing 

"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"

from the header.

Comment: I tried your code on one of my page, and it works. So I suppose Facebook stored your first test. Because you use Etag may be -really may be- Facebook don't try to reload your page. So first of all I mention for you that to rename this page to another or remove Etag via .htaccess .

Answer (score -2):

at the top of page use

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

instead of

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```